# How to embed google iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, frame

Google seems to be blocking websites which use iframes. Of course I'm using google with its trademark and embedded it in an iframe. But for some reason it never works.

Anyone knows how to bypass it?

http://jsfiddle.net/EgurZ/

Thanks

Comment: If they don't wan't that you embed their's webpage into your's I don't recommend to do it, because otherwise you could get problems with them ;-)

Comment: It's an intentional [click-jacking defense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options).

Comment: If you wan't to add a Google search in your website, use a Google Custom Search for this.

Comment: Why do you want that?? they give you API for a lot of things, search included. Use that.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot bypass it in modern browsers in any way, they simply refuse to display websites in iframe that send a [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header with `DENY` (or `SAMEORIGIN` is already enough). It doesn't even come down to javascript.

Comment: You *can* bypass it, just use this URL: https://www.google.com/?igu=1
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/EgurZ/49/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link instead of https://google.com/ , it works pretty good:

> https://www.google.com/search?igu=1

With specific word you can use this link:

> https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q=YOUR+WORD

Than iframe should looks as this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"></iframe>
```