# Address bar and iframe

Tags: iframe

It works on Chrome and Firefox but do you know why it's not working on Internet Explorer and how can it work with google.com, ebay, hotmail, ...
Or maybe you have a different code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#showUrl {
border:2px solid #0A9;
height:90%;
width:95%;
}
#url {
width:30em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadUrl() {
    var url = document.getElementById( 'url' ).value;
    var showUrl = document.getElementById( 'showUrl' );
    showUrl.src = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Enter URL to load: <input type="text" id="url" />
    <input type="button" value="Load URL" onclick="loadUrl()" />
</form>
<iframe id="showUrl"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed google iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139474/how-to-embed-google-iframe) -- TL;DR those sites have headers which prevent them from appearing in frames.